# How to get mongodb database name where connect client is defined in 4.x driver

Tags: java, mongodb

In 3.x driver API, it is possible to retrieve database name where user is defined and currently connected. Namely, I have a user defined under admin and when I connect to mongodb server, I can retrieve database name of the connected user with the following code (as defined in https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html#getSource()):

```
com.mongodb.MongoClient client = new com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", credential, clientOptions);
String userDB = client.getCredential().getSource();
```

However, I cannot find same/similar method for 4.x API for the com.mongodb.client.MongoClient (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html).

Is it missing or it is me that couldn't find that function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is getSource in the 4.1 api at: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html?is-external=true

db.getName() is a server-side way to get that. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getName/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes getSource is available under MongoCredential but it is not accessible through com.mongodb.client.MongoClient.

db.getName() returns the database name where you are currently working on instead of the one user is defined.

Comment: In 3.12 it's in MongoCredential too. I guess I'm confused as to why you linked to mongoCredential for 3.12? Does your code not work in versions 4+?

Comment: There are 2 MongoClient implementations. com.mongodb.MongoClient and com.mongodb.client.MongoClient. With using first client I can use MongoCredential but latter one does not have a get method to understand where the authenticated user is defined under which database.